# Class defined within template class, don't understand how to use it and define it

Tags: c++, templates, hashmap

I have been given the skeleton of a template that I need to code. I have never really dealt with templates. The weird thing about this template is that it requires us to code a class within the template itself - not just class functions, but a whole new class. Here is the code just for the template (I inserted a few lines of code within some of the methods just to start off, they are inconsequential to my issue):

## include

```
template<class K, class V> class HMap
{
 private:
 // insert instance variables
 // insert constants (if any)

 public:
 class MapEntry
 {
    private:
        K key;
        V value;

    public:
    /**
     * Creates a MapEntry.
     * 
     * @param akey the key
     * @param avalue the value
     */
    MapEntry(K akey, V avalue)
    {
        key = akey;
        value = avalue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the key for this entry.
     * 
     * @return the key for this entry
     */
    K getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value for this entry.
     * 
     * @return the value for this entry
     */
    V getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value for this entry.
     * 
     * @param newValue
     * @return the previous value for this entry
     */
    V setValue(V newValue)
    {
        V oldval;
        oldval = value;
        value = newvalue;
        return oldval;
    }
};
```

When you create an object of the HMap template type, how would you use the MapEntry class within it? I'm so completely new to templates, I'm kind of lost and don't know where to begin with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`HMap<Int, Double>::MapEntry` to refer inner class. But why you want to expose inner structure?

Maybe it would be easier to do such (I implement list of pair, not hash, because I am lazy)

```
template <type Key, type Value>
class HashMap {
private:
struct entry { Key key, Value value};
std::list<entry> map;
public:
  HashMap() {};
  void add_element(Key key, Value value)
    {
      entry e = {.key = key, .value = value};
      map.push_back(e);
    };
}
```

Comment: Our professor said as much - he said its typically bad programming practice to make the inner structure exposed, but that it was the most feasible for this lab. This is his code skeleton, not mine :)

Comment: Then I answered your question: `HMap<Int,Double>::MapEntry`.